# Add multiple options in array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this var

```
var allwords = {};
```

And i need push more options in this array like:

```
allwords.push = {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"};
allwords.push = {"Ctrl-pause": "closewindow"};
```

And look like this:

```
allwords = {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete", "Ctrl-pause": "closewindow"};
```

How can't i do?

Comment: That isn't an array, for a start. I suggest setting aside your current task and working through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is for [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) objects. For traditional objects, assign the properties manually like

```js
var allwords = {};

allwords["Ctrl-Space"] = "autocomplete";
allwords["Ctrl-pause"] = "closewindow";

console.log(allwords);
```